# how to force open new tab / window for javascript?

Tags: javascript, counter, visitor-pattern, new-window, visitor-statistic

I want to install supercounter in a page:

```
< !-- BEGIN: Powered by Supercounters.com -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://widget.supercounters.com/online_t.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">sc_online_t(244858,"Users Online","170ddb");</script>
< !-- END: Powered by Supercounters.com -->`
```

So, how can I open the stats page in a new tab or window, not same window?

Answer (score 0):

If there's a link that the stat page uses, you could use [window.open](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp)

*`window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)`*

```
window.open('http://www.URL.com', _blank);
```

This will open the page in a new window

Comment: Actually the answer references what you're asking. You just haven't worded it properly for what you want. How does the stats page open? something has to be ran to open it

Comment: i dont know what the url to put in the bracket... u can understand it by using it first at http://www.supercounters.com/onlinecounter